# sub-menus slide when background sliding in

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a navigation that has a background image slide effect. The main idea is to have three list items that contain the same background image but with a different position. The background image for each item will be animated to slide into place in different times.
  The background image sliding direction from the list item in the middle will depend on which item the user was before: coming from the right, it will slide from the left and vice versa.
  On top of that we will have sub-menus that appear with their semi-transparent background sliding in. they will slide into their places and change color.
  There's a website have the same effect: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/BeautifulBackgroundImageNavigation/
  I have also put my coding in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rctyuzb/

For my work, the sub-menus is not moving, they stick with the image even the image they are with is not sliding in, I think maybe the reason could be the change of the size, since I'm doing this for a 480*800 phone size, that's why I have to change all the size to fit in the phone screen.

Coding that could not b included in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rctyuzb/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<title>About Us</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="http://rafaelcastrocouto.github.io/jquery.bgpos/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">    </script>
```

Comment: What you have tried till ??

Comment: @Prog I have just updated the jsfiddle